# Can't display posts using Custom Post Type - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

I'm feeling close to finishing this. In short, I can't seem to display posts.
For example I have:

```
http://somedomain.org/tours //Displays all categories
http://somedomain.org/tours/gbr //Displays all posts in category
http://somedomain.org/tours/gbr/my-post //Should display post in category
```

`http://somedomain.org/tours/gbr/my-post` doesn't display, I get a there's nothing here, 404 error. But if I go to:

```
http://somedomain.org/toursgbr/my-post
```

It does in fact, display the post ("toursgbr" has no forward slash if you're looking for the difference)

I am using the latest WordPress. I am using the plugin:
Custom Post Type Permalinks

I have the following code in the functions.php file:

```
// Our custom post type function
    function create_posttype() {

    register_post_type( 'tours',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Tours' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Tour' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'tours', 'with_front' => TRUE),
            'cptp_permalink_structure' => '%tour_category%/%postname%',
            'hierarchical' => true //A added
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );

function my_taxonomies_tours() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Tour Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Tour Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Tour Categories' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Tour Categories' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Tour Category' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Tour Category:' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Tour Category' ), 
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Tour Category' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Tour Category' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Tour Category' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Tour Categories' ),
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'tours')
  );
  register_taxonomy( 'tour_category', 'tours', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_tours', 0 );
```

The line of code:

```
'cptp_permalink_structure' => '%tour_category%/%postname%',
```

If I add the forward slash, so it's:

```
'cptp_permalink_structure' => '/%tour_category%/%postname%',
```

That's when I can't view posts. Any help in the right direction would be fantastic. I do have other categories other than gbr and posts can have multiple categories. I thought that might be important information